# Cosmic neutrino background temperature

Tags: cosmology, temperature, neutrinos, cosmic-microwave-background

In my cosmology lecture course, we derived the temperature of the cosmic neutrino background as

\begin{equation}
T_{\nu} = \left(\frac{4}{11}\right) ^ {1/3} T_{\gamma} \,.
\end{equation}
Since the temperature of the cosmic microwave background today is $T_{\gamma}=2.73K$, the temperature of the cosmic neutrino background today is $T_{\nu} = 1.95K$ according to the above equation. However, my lecturer mentioned that we believe that neutrinos have recently become non-relativistic. But doesn't the above equation assume that both temperatures are inversely proportional to the scale factor, which is true only for ultra-relativistic particles? So once neutrinos become non-relativistic, $T_{\nu}(a)$ changes and the above equation is not right and we cannot say that $T_{\nu}=1.95K$ today. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the universe expands, the cosmic background neutrinos maintain a fixed relativistic Fermi-Dirac distribution as they cool because the neutrino number is approximately conserved. There is much lower occupation of high energy states and the distribution *does not depend on the neutrino mass or how relativistic they are*
$$F(p,T) = \frac{1}{\exp(pc/kT_\nu) + 1}\ .$$
Both neutrino momentum and the neutrino "temperature" decrease with the scale factor as $(1+z)^{-1}$. i.e $T_\nu(a)$ doesn't change.

The calculation of the current neutrino temperature only assumes that the neutrino phase-space distribution retains the form above. The entropy of a gas governed by this distribution is $\propto g T^3$ and entropy conservation then leads to the $(4/11)^{1/3}$ factor.

Where the distinction between relativistic and non-relativistic neutrinos does come in is if you were to try and estimate an rms speed because it does not directly correspond to temperature as in a Maxwell-Boltzmann gas. Whilst the energy of relativistic particles falls as $a^{-1}$, the energy of non-relativistic particles falls as $a^{-2}$.